# how to get exponential-function from given points?

Tags: exponential-function

the given function is $f(x)=b * a^{-x} + c$ 
the 2 given points are N(1|0) and M(0|2)

What I did so far was inserting the points in the function and solve after c 
so I got $c=-\frac{b}{a}$ and $c=b-2$

I don't know how to proceed at this point, can someone explain the next steps?

the given solution from the book is $f(x)=4*2^{-x}-2$
thanks!

Comment: You can't. you have three parameters and only two equations.

Comment: so theres a printing error on the sheets, thank you!

Comment: For instance $$\begin{cases} 5\cdot\left(\frac53\right)^{-1}-3=0\\ 5\cdot\left(\frac53\right)^{-0}-3=2\end{cases}$$